# Reading Variable names into a list

Tags: python, list, pandas

Given a csv file that has been read into a dataframe, is there a way to read the 0th row (the column/variable names) into a list programmatically, to be used at a later time?

I attempted to iterate over the columns like so: `for i in cols: column = df[i]`

Comment: "is there a way to read the...row into a list programmatically" Yes there is. What have you tried already?

Comment: `for i in cols: column = df[i]` was what I was trying

Comment: Are you wanting just the column names from the csv or from a dataframe?

Comment: @EdChum I am trying to cycle through all the columns to compute a numerical quantity for each column via a 'for' loop. I don't know which of those things accomplishes those tasks, either maybe?

Comment: So you want just the columns names? `cols = list(df.columns)` would give you that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `nrows=1` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'mycsv.csv', nrows=1)
cols = list(df.columns)
```